# Why can't I install Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure?

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to use Nuget to install this package into my solution. To do this, I type "Install-Package Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure -verbose" into my Package Manager Console. After doing this, the package fails to install, and I get the following information:

> GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration3-gz-semver2/microsoft.web.infrastructure/index.json
>     OK https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration3-gz-semver2/microsoft.web.infrastructure/index.json 33ms
>
> Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.1.0.0' with respect to project 'My_Project', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6'
>
> Package Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure from source nuget.org gathered from cache.
>
> Total number of results gathered : 1
>
> Gathering dependency information took 14.22 ms
>
> Summary of time taken to gather dependencies per source :
>
> Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.1.0.0' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
>
> Resolving dependency information took 0 ms
>
> Resolving actions to install package 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.1.0.0'
>
> Resolved actions to install package 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.1.0.0'
>
> Retrieving package 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure 1.0.0' from 'nuget.org'.
>
> For adding package 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.1.0.0' to project 'My_Project' that targets 'net46'.
>
> For adding package 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.1.0.0' to project 'My_Project' that targets 'net46'.
>
> Adding package 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.1.0.0' to folder 'C:\Path\to\my\project\packages'
>
> Install failed. Rolling back...
>
> Package 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.1.0.0' does not exist in project 'My_Project'
>
> Removing package 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.1.0.0' from folder 'C:\Path\to\my\project\packages'
>
> Install-Package : TF400024: The change on C:\Path\to\my\project\packages\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.1.0.0.0\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.1.0.0.0.nupkg cannot be undone because a file already exists at 
>   C:\Path\to\my\project\packages\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.1.0.0.0\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.1.0.0.0.nupkg. The file must be deleted from disk for the undo to succeed.
>
> At line:1 char:1
>   + Install-Package Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure -verbose
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
>
> Time Elapsed: 00:00:00.4203958
>   One or more packages could not be completely uninstalled: 'C:\Path\to\my\project\packages\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.1.0.0.0'.
>
> Restart Visual Studio to finish uninstall.

I have tried deleting the "packages" folder and restarting Visual Studio, but to no avail. I can install other packages, such as NLog, just fine. Why can't I install this package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I had added a corrupted "packages/Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.1.0.0.0" folder to my TFS source control. This folder did not contain the "lib" directory, which is necessary in order to load the reference. Instead, it only contained the "Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.1.0.0.0.nupkg" archive. To fix this, I extracted the "lib" directory from the archive using [7-zip](http://7-zip.org). After doing this, my "packages/Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.1.0.0.0" directory had the following structure:

- lib

  - net40

    - Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll
- Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.1.0.0.0.nupkg

Finally, I opened the solution in Visual Studio, and I expanded the project's "References" tab. I noticed that "Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" had already been added to the project, but had a yellow "error" symbol on it. To fix this, I simply right-clicked it and selected "Properties."

After following these two steps, I was able to successfully build my project.

Answer (score 0):

Is your packages.config file in source control? In the case of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15441609/nuget-package-updates-package-config-remove-issue-tf400024), the issue was the file was deleted from source but still existed (not deleted). I would make sure your packages.config is checked-in/squared away in source control with any changes.