# Nuget package won't install

Tags: c#, nuget, owin

I am trying to install owin in a project and it fails with the below error its not real descriptive. If I create a new project it works just fine. How can I find out what is causing the error

I updated with -verbose but no extra info

```
Adding package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.2.2.1' to folder 'c:\Workspace\Ruby\pfg.producealliance.com\packages'
Install failed. Rolling back...
Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.2.2.1' does not exist in project 'Ruby.Web'
Removing package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.2.2.1' from folder 'c:\Workspace\Ruby\pfg.producealliance.com\packages'
TF400024: The change on c:\Workspace\Ruby\pfg.producealliance.com\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.2.2.1\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.2.2.1.nupkg cannot be undone because a file already exists at c:\Workspace\Ruby\pfg.producealliance.com\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.2.2.1\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.2.2.1.nupkg. The file must be deleted from disk for the undo to succeed.
Install-Package : TF400024: The change on c:\Workspace\Ruby\pfg.producealliance.com\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.2.2.1\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.2.2.1.nupkg cannot be undone because a file already exists at 
c:\Workspace\Ruby\pfg.producealliance.com\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.2.2.1\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.2.2.1.nupkg. The file must be deleted from disk for the undo to succeed.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin -ProjectName Ruby.Web  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
```

Comment: are you targetting .net framework or .net core?

Comment: .net framework is this for .net core ?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I find out what is causing the error[?]

Pass the `-Verbose` flag to `Install-Package`. The output will hopefully tell you more precisely what went wrong. Perhaps a file is in use and cannot be copied or modified?

UPDATE: 
Thanks to the additional info provided by the OP, I think [Nuget Package updates & Package.config remove issue (TF400024)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15441609/nuget-package-updates-package-config-remove-issue-tf400024) answers your problem (hint: it's related to your project not being checked out from source control). Check out the project and try again.

Comment: this should be a comment.

Comment: @downvoters - be fair, the OP's question really was how to see more info about what was failing

Comment: Updated question

Comment: Even with the -verbose flag, my install was failing with no real description or error. In my case, I had a pending change (TFS) to the Packages folder that much have been blocking write access to the folder. As soon as I checked in my pending change, it installed as expected. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.